# Deleting component from array not working unless wrapped in div

Tags: reactjs

I have a CommentList component and a CommentForm component. My CommentList has an array of CommentForm component in its state called comments.

This is the render of the CommentList:

```
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <button type='button' className='btn btn-default' onClick= {this.onAddComment}>Ajouter commentaire</button>
        <br /><br />
          {this.state.comments}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

This is my delete method which I pass to the child as a prop.

```
  onDelete (i) {
    var comments = this.state.comments
    delete comments[i]
    this.setState({ comments: comments })
  }
```

I just now realised that the delete is not working unless I wrap "this.state.comments" in a div like so:

```
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <button type='button' className='btn btn-default' onClick={this.onAddComment}>Ajouter commentaire</button>
        <br /><br />
        <div>
          {this.state.comments}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I know I need to wrap my Component in a div before rendering but why is the delete not working unless I wrap my list?

EDIT:

This is the function I use to set the state and populate my comments array

```
  loadComments () {
    Axios.get(`${API}/${this.props.candidate_id}/comments.json`)
      .then(response => {
        let comments = response.data.map((obj, index) => {
          return (
            <CommentForm
              key={index}
              index={index}
              baskets={this.state.baskets}
              comment={obj}
              onDelete={this.onDelete}
              candidate_id={this.props.candidate_id} />
          )
        })
        this.setState({ comments: comments })
      })
  }
```

Comment: It doesn't make any sense. If your `comments` variable is an object (and I guess it is, because you are using `delete` keyword) you can't just drop it inside JSX. You app should crash instantly.

Comment: It is an array of component, cant I use the delete keyword on a component? I added the function where I set the state in the question

Comment: You can't use `delete` keyword on arrays. I mean, you can, but it's not a good option. Use slice or splice instead.

Comment: But why is it not working unless I wrap it in a div?

Comment: Can you put in a basic structure of how `comments` looks like and how is the `onDelete` method invoked ?

Comment: I guess reconciliation is ignoring because both before and after object reference is the same. Point to new Object may be by using Object.assign({}, comments) and assign that in your setState

Answer (score 0):

Use slice instead of delete. You need to get new array because state is immutable.

```
  onDelete(i) {
    this.setState(ps => {
      [...ps.comments.slice(0, i), ...ps.comments.slice(i + 1)];
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 issues with the code

- When you look at how `onDelete` is called, your referring to the method directly but the parameter that will be mapped to `i` will be undefined.

Change

```
     onDelete={this.onDelete}

               to 

     onDelete={() => this.onDelete(index)}
```

- Mutating entries is not a good approach. Instead build a new list and update the state instead.

I also suggest that `comments` only contain the response directly and use `jsx` in the `render` instead of maintaining that in the state.

```
loadComments() {
    Axios.get(`${API}/${this.props.candidate_id}/comments.json`).then(
      response => {
        this.setState({ comments: response.data });
      }
    );
  }

  onDelete(i) {
    let updatedComments = this.state.comments.filter((comment, index) => {
      return index !== i;
    });

    this.setState({ comments: updatedComments });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button
          type="button"
          className="btn btn-default"
          onClick={this.onAddComment}
        >
          Ajouter commentaire
        </button>
        <br />
        <br />
        <div>
          {this.state.comments.map((obj, index) => {
            return (
              <CommentForm
                key={index}
                index={index}
                baskets={this.state.baskets}
                comment={obj}
                onDelete={() => this.onDelete(index)}
                candidate_id={this.props.candidate_id}
              />
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```